# Get complete Object from Array in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, core-data

I am stuck in one problem.I am not able to get full object from an array.I have array of class objects and i need to get list of unique elements.i write this code

```
[objects valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.B1_UM"]
```

But the problem is my class have many elements and i get list of only unique B1_UM,instead i need list of objects where B1_UM is unique

Comment: Get the array, put it into `NSSet`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to do that "manually" by enumerating over all objects,
and using a set to keep track of which keys have already been added.
Something like this (untested):

```
NSMutableSet *b1ums = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableArray *uniqueObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
for (MyClass *obj in objects) {
   if (![b1ums containsObject:obj.b1_um]) {
       [b1ums addObject:obj.b1_um];    // remember key
       [uniqueObjects addObject:obj];  // add object
   }
}
```

Theoretically, you *could* override `isEqual` and `hash` in your custom class
to consider two objects identical if the `b1_um` property is equal.
But that might be a bit overkill.

*Edit:* I had not noticed that your question is tagged with [core-data]. 
For managed objects, an alternative approach would be possible: Execute a fetch request
with `NSDictionaryResultType` and set `propertiesToGroupBy` to the "b1_um" attribute.
Then you can pick one object from each group in the returned result.